# How do I set a dynamic style property in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set the minimum height of an element is a `.vue` page. The style attribute has a bind to the `styleObject`

```html
    <b-container class="mt-3" v-bind:style="styleObject">
```

I'm using mounted in my script to set up the styleObject.

```js
    export default {
      data: function() {
        containerHeight: null,
        styleObject: {
          minHeight: this.containerHeight
        }
      },
      mounted() {

        let headerHeight = document.querySelector('#header').offsetHeight; 
        let navHeight = document.querySelector('#main-menu').offsetHeight; 
        let footerHeight = document.querySelector('#footer').offsetHeight; 

        let ht = screen.height - (headerHeight + navHeight + footerHeight);

        alert(ht);//the calculated height is displayed

        this.containerHeight = ht + "px";
      }
    }
```

The container height does not adjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use other data props as a value for another data prop when you declare them as they won't be reactive.

Avoid:

```
styleObject: {
      minHeight: this.containerHeight
    }
```

Just set it to null and do

```
styleObject: {
      minHeight: null
    }
```

```
this.styleObject.minHeight = ht + "px";
```

Comment: Alternatively you can define `styleObject` as a computed property—that will make it reactive.